# How to add Faraday request body into Datadog tracing in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trace, datadog, faraday, apm

I'm trying to configure Faraday tracing in a Rails application using Datadog.

I've set up the Faraday -> Datadog connection:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'ddtrace'

Datadog.configure do |c|
  c.use :faraday
end

Faraday.post("http://httpstat.us/200", {foo: 1, bar: 2}.to_json)
Faraday.get("http://httpstat.us/201?foo=1&bar=2")
```

It works well, the requests are being logged to Datadog.

But those logs do not contain any request parameters, nevertheless GET or POST.

[image: GET request log]  [image: POST request log]

Any adviсe on how to get the request params/body logged to Datadog?

Comment: Does this help https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/ruby/#faraday?

Comment: I see there's an extra `options` there. Maybe that's what's missing. I am not using Datadog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, by default the only things sent to Datadog from Faraday as part of the span in terms of the HTTP request are are:

```
      span.set_tag(Datadog::Ext::HTTP::URL, env[:url].path)
      span.set_tag(Datadog::Ext::HTTP::METHOD, env[:method].to_s.upcase)
      span.set_tag(Datadog::Ext::NET::TARGET_HOST, env[:url].host)
      span.set_tag(Datadog::Ext::NET::TARGET_PORT, env[:url].port)
```

Source: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-rb/blob/e391d2eb64d3c6151a4bdd2710c6a8c7c1d57457/lib/ddtrace/contrib/faraday/middleware.rb#L54

The body of the request is not set in the http part of the span by default, only the URL, HTTP method, host and port are.

However, with [manual instrumentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/custom_instrumentation/ruby?tab=manuallyinstrumentedspans) you can add anything you want to the span, so you could write an extension or monkey-patch to the Faraday middleware to add the body and parameters to the span:

```
span.set_tag("http.body", env[:body])
span.set_tag("http.params", env[:params])
```

An example monkey patch:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'ddtrace'
require 'ddtrace/contrib/faraday/middleware'

module FaradayExtension
  private
  def annotate!(span, env, options)
    # monkey patch to add body to span
    span.set_tag("http.body", env[:body]) unless env[:body].to_s.strip.empty?
    span.set_tag("http.query", env[:url].query) if env[:url].query
    super
  end
end

Datadog::Contrib::Faraday::Middleware.prepend(FaradayExtension)

Datadog.configure do |c|
  c.use :faraday
end

Faraday.post("http://httpstat.us/200", {foo: 1, bar: 2}.to_json)
Faraday.get("http://httpstat.us/201?foo=1&bar=2")
```

This worked for me in my testing:

[image: Post]
[image: Get]

NB: I am a Datadog employee, but not on the engineering team, just wanted to be transparent!